# Draw 2 stacking was wrong or official account played a prank?

Tags: uno

There was a [viral tweet](https://twitter.com/realunogame/status/1314599677854179331?lang=en) by UNO's official twitter page:

[image]

This got a lot of backlashes and many people still allow +2 stacking. But is there any official historical evidence to support either side before this tweet?

Comment: The two seem to be talking past each other. It seems to me that scribb24 describes this situation: 1) Player A plays a Draw 2. 2) Player B draws two cards and loses their turn. 3) Player C (“not the one that drew two”) has a Draw 2 in hand and wants to know if they can play it. The answer by realUNOgame confirms Player B’s actions and says nothing about Player C. (Skimming the replies, I found at least one respondent saying this, but with no answer from realUNOgame.)

Comment: @TimPederick I believe the official rules state (emphasis mine): "Every player views his/her cards and tries to match the card in the Discard Pile. You have to match either by the number, color, or the **symbol/Action**." So if player A plays a green +2 and player B draws and skips their turn, then player C is now allowed to play a red +2 if they happen to have one. I don't see any other way to read that part of the rules.

Comment: There's a *yellow* Twitter check mark now too? I can't keep up with these anymore....

Comment: @Arthur The [official rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf) more explicitly say a Draw Two Card "may only be played on a matching color or on another Draw Two card".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Draw card stacking is not part of the basic Uno game rules, but it is a house rule used so frequently that Mattel have included it in the [bundled rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/UNO%20Basic%20IS.pdf) as a variant called "Progressive Uno".

The Progressive Uno rules are as follows:

> Same rules as UNO® card game, except:
>
> 1. When a player plays a Draw Two card, the next player may play another Draw Two
>    card, causing the next player to draw 4 cards.
> 2. Same rule applies to Wild Draw Four cards:
>    When a player plays a Wild Draw Four card, the next player may play another Wild
>    Draw Four card, causing the next player to draw 8 cards. The last player to play a
>    consecutive Wild Draw Four card calls the color to continue play. If a Wild Draw Four
>    card is played illegally and the player is challenged, the usual rules apply (See
>    FUNCTIONS OF ACTION CARDS), except that the penalty will increase depending on
>    the number of cards played.
> 3. Players can continue to play consecutive Draw Two or Wild Draw Four cards, as long
>    as they have them in their hands. For example, if 4 players in a row played Draw Two
>    cards, the next player (who doesn’t have a Draw Two card) would have to draw 8
>    cards.
> 4. You can only play one Draw Two or Wild Draw Four during your turn, even though
>    you may have multiples of these cards in your hand.